# How can we get nginx access log on laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx

As title, I need to get data from nginx access log to handle and store in db. So anyone have any ideas about this ? Thank you for reading this post

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. I mean if you know where the access log is it should be pretty straight-forward to read it and parse the entries to do whatever you want with them. Is your question about finding the log? About reading the lines? About parsing the lines? or is it how to pass the parsed data to a database. Just to point out, each of these on its own is a valid question here but this is assuming you show us a relevant attempt on your part to do this. Please update your question accordingly so we know what it is you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm so sorry because my question's not really clear. I mean I know where the access log is, but currently I dont know how to read that file in my coding, because it is located at another container. @apokryfos

Comment: If they are in different containers then it is generally not possible to read files between containers unless you create a new volume and mount it on both containers as a means to share part of their filesystem. I'm not too sure how to do this in practice since I never actually have done it but https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ might have more info. Just make sure nginx logs on the shared volume and the shared volume is mounted in both containers

Comment: Yes thanks so much, I also reading about how to share data with volumns and it seem work @apokryfos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be storing nginx logs in the DB and trying to read them through Laravel, it will very quickly cause you performance and storage issues especially on production. Other issues will be if you have various servers, how would you aggregate all the logs?

Common practice is to use NoSQL for such tasks. So you can setup another dedicated server where you export all your logs and analyze them. You use an exporter that you install on every one of your servers, point them to your log file and they export the logs to a central logs server. You can set this up yourself using something like ELK stack. With ELK stack you can use filebeat and logstash for this.

Better would be to use some of the services out there such as GCP logging, splunk, etc. You have to pay for them but they offer a lot of benefits. Splunk would provide you with an exporter, with gcp you could use fluentd. If you are using containers, you can also setup a fluentd container and shared volumes to export the logs.